# Do action after another ajax function ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I'm searching a solution for this:
I have a function that updates the content of a table in my application.

```
function prev_update(cli_id){
    $("#list").empty();
    $("#list").append("<tr><td colspan=11><img src='images/loading.gif' alt=loading title=loading /></td></tr>");
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'json/get.php?t=2&id='+cli_id, 
        dataType    : 'json',
        encode      : true
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        $("#list").empty();
        if ((data)["prev_list"]) {  
            $.each((data)["prev_list"], function( i, val ) {
                $( "#list" ).append(val);
            });
            $("#edit").hide("slow");
        } else {
            $("#list").append("<tr><td colspan=11>&nbsp;</td></tr>");                       
        }
    });
};
```

In another function I'm updating a row of a table, when I finish to edit the content of a row of the table i launch a similar function but in the .done row I call the prev_update function and AFTER this is finished I have to push a button in the updated table content, for review the modifications...
Here's the code:

```
$("#prev_mod").on("click",(function( event ) {
     $('#loading_img').css('display','inline');
     header_print();
     $.ajax({
         type       : 'POST',
         url        : 'json/post.php?mod='+$('#prev_id').val(),
         data       : $("#form_sog").serialize(),
         dataType   : 'json',
         encode : true
   })
   .done(function(data) {
        if ((data)["success"]===false) {    
            $('#form_edit').hide('slow');
            prev_update();
            $('#edit_'+$('#prev_id').val()).click();
        });
   });
}));
```

I have to wait when prev_update() function ends then click the button because the button is in the table that is updating.
I tried to use also deferred object but it doesn't works (maybe for my error).
I can't edit the function prev_update because it's used by other functions.

Comment: When you say "prev_update() function ends", what exactly do you mean? Do you mean all the animations in it finish or do you mean that it just runs and is done doing what it started?  And, how do you not end up with an infinite cycle here since `prev_update()` calls itself unendingly.

Comment: the second code I've posted is from another function.
When I said function ends I mean the function have done all the process it started (ajax request and other animations)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `.done` you can use `.then` to organize your code. This is because `.then` can be chained

Not tested but it can be like this

```
function prev_update(cli_id){
    $("#list").empty();
    $("#list").append("<tr><td colspan=11><img src='images/loading.gif' alt=loading title=loading /></td></tr>");
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'json/get.php?t=2&id='+cli_id, 
        dataType    : 'json',
        encode      : true
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        $("#list").empty();
        // rest of code
    }).then(function(data) {
        if ((data)["success"]===false) {    
            // rest of code
        };
   });
```

Comment: `data` will not be passed to the 2nd chained `.then()` handler unless you return it from the previous one.

Comment: @jfriend00 that is right , I also feel that this may result in never ending execution since in second `.then` there is again a reference to `prev_update` which will led execution of first .`then` and so on

Comment: the function prev_update can be used by other functions, so I can't modify prev_update function, but I have to work with another function. Sorry if my question was not clear...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know when everything inside of `prev_update()` is done, you HAVE to modify it to keep track of the async operations in it and to return a promise.  Then, the caller can use that returned promise to know when things are done.

So, inside of `prev_update()`, the two async operations are the ajax call and the `.hide()` animation.  The hide animation occurs inside of the completion handler for the ajax operation.  So, if you change `.done()` to `.then()`, we can chain together these promises and return a single promise that will tell the caller when everything is done.

jQuery has a `.promise()` method that will get us a promise that is linked to any jQuery animation so if we just get the promise for the animation, we can return it and it will chain to the parent promise.  If there was no animation, then we can just return nothing and the promise chain will continue.

This does not change the functionality of `prev_update()` at all - it just returns a promise that tracks its completion (when you were previously not returning anything).

That can work like this:

```
function prev_update(cli_id){
    $("#list").empty();
    $("#list").append("<tr><td colspan=11><img src='images/loading.gif' alt=loading title=loading /></td></tr>");
    return $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'json/get.php?t=2&id='+cli_id, 
        dataType    : 'json',
        encode      : true
    }).then(function(data) {
        var p;
        $("#list").empty();
        if ((data)["prev_list"]) {  
            $.each((data)["prev_list"], function( i, val ) {
                $( "#list" ).append(val);
            });
            p = $("#edit").hide("slow").promise();
        } else {
            $("#list").append("<tr><td colspan=11>&nbsp;</td></tr>");                       
        }
        // return promise if there was one
        return p;
    });
};
```

So, then you can use this in your other code like this:

```
$("#prev_mod").on("click",(function( event ) {
     $('#loading_img').css('display','inline');
     header_print();
     $.ajax({
         type       : 'POST',
         url        : 'json/post.php?mod='+$('#prev_id').val(),
         data       : $("#form_sog").serialize(),
         dataType   : 'json',
         encode : true
   }).then(function(data) {
        if ((data)["success"]===false) {    
            $('#form_edit').hide('slow');
            prev_update().then(function() {
                // apply click when everything in prev_update() is done
                $('#edit_'+$('#prev_id').val()).click();
            });
        });
   });
}));
```